# MySQL Select Based on Conditional Select

Tags: mysql, sql, select, conditional-statements

I have my structure set up so that any entry could contain a reference to another entry to fill in the missing details.

```
ID,  NAME, DESCRIPTION, REFERENCE
0,  Stuff,      Things, -1
1,       ,            , 0
2, Things,       Stuff, -1
```

I want to be able to return all the results for the table and if an entry requires a reference to another entry to complete the data, to fill the reference field with the data. I also want to keep the original ID of the reference field. I also want the fields that don't require a reference to be left alone.

```
SELECT `ID`, `REFERENCE` FROM `details` as `t`
     IF `REFERENCE` != -1 THEN
          SELECT *, `t`.`REFERENCE` as `ORIGINAL_ID` FROM `details` WHERE `ID` = `t`.`REFERENCE`
     ELSE
          SELECT * FROM `details` WHERE `ID` = `t`.`ID`
```

Obviously that won't work, but I'm just trying to demonstrate to you what I think I want. Is this possible? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get close with something like this:

```
SELECT
    t.ID,
    t.Reference,
    COALESCE(reffed.Name, t.name) AS name,
    COALESCE(reffed.whatever, t.whatever) AS whatever,
    COALESCE(... and so on ...)
  FROM details t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN details reffed ON t.Reference = reffed.id
```

If there's a referenced value it will take precedence over the "base" value because of the `COALESCE`.

If `Reference = -1` or if `Reference` doesn't point to a valid `id` the referenced value will be null so `COALESCE` will return the "base" value (`t.whatever` instead of `reffed.whatever`).

Note that this assumes you won't have an actual row where `details.id = -1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a `left outer join` and some logic in the `select` statement.

The following code adds two new columns.  These incorporate the logic that they pull from the referenced row, if any, and then from the original data:

```
select d.*,
       (case when Reference >= 0 then dref.name else d.name end) as UsedName,
       (case when Reference >= 0 then dref.description else d.description end) as UsedDescription
from details d left outer join
     details dref
     on d.reference = dref.id
```